# MySQL Error Code: 1526. Table has no partition for value from column_list

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySql and I am trying to create a Partition in a table,  using a stored procedure.
**I have the following table in MySql -**

```
CREATE TABLE `snapshot` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `latest_transaction_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `balance` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `last_transaction_timestamp` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `last_transaction_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `snapshot_date` date NOT NULL,
  `year` smallint(6) NOT NULL
) 
/*!50500 PARTITION BY LIST  COLUMNS(`year`)
(PARTITION snapshot_2017 VALUES IN (2017),
 PARTITION snapshot_2016 VALUES IN (2016),
 PARTITION snapshot_2018 VALUES IN (2018)) */
```

**I have written a stored procedure which is -**
1. Getting current year name
2. Adding a prefix to the year
3. And then creating a new partition, using the `prefix+year` name

The idea is the data of a certain year, should belong to that particular year’s partition.
**Following is the stored procedure -**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `process_snapshot`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE snapshot_year INT;
    DECLARE partition_name VARCHAR(17);
    DECLARE isPartionPresent VARCHAR(64);

    SET snapshot_year := DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y');
    SET partition_name := CONCAT('snapshot_',snapshot_year);

    SET isPartionPresent := (SELECT DISTINCT PARTITION_NAME
        FROM
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS
        WHERE
            TABLE_NAME = 'snapshot'
            AND PARTITION_NAME = partition_name);

    IF isPartionPresent IS NULL THEN
        SET @addPartition = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE snapshot ADD PARTITION (PARTITION ', partition_name, ' VALUES IN (', snapshot_year,'))');
        PREPARE _stmt FROM @addPartition;
        EXECUTE _stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE _stmt;

    END IF;
END
```

**I am getting the following error when I run the SP -**

```
Error Code: 1526. Table has no partition for value from column_list
```

**However, if I run the following SP separately, I am able to create a partition successfully,**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `create_table_partition`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE snapshot_year INT;
    DECLARE partition_name VARCHAR(17);

    SET snapshot_year := DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y');
    SET partition_name := CONCAT('snapshot_',snapshot_year);

    SET @addPartition = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE snapshot ADD PARTITION (PARTITION ', partition_name, ' VALUES IN (', snapshot_year,'))');
    PREPARE _stmt FROM @addPartition;
    EXECUTE _stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE _stmt;
END
```

But if I call this SP, from my main SP, it gives the same error,
What could be the issue?

Comment: Don't give variables or parameters the same name as table columns - PARTITION_NAME = partition_name is comparing information.schema.partitions.partition_name to itself

Comment: Thanks, @P.Salmon that solved the issue